# Passing environmental variables to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm trying to publish a Shiny app to shinyapps.io but the app requires a Quandl API connection. I don't want to put the API key in my code so I use a `.Renviron` file to store the API key.

This is the content of the `.Renviron` file:

```
QUANDL_API_KEY=api_key_goes_here
```

This is the content of the .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r}
print(Sys.getenv("QUANDL_API_KEY"))
```
````

When I deploy to shinyapps.io nothing is printed out. But when I run locally, the key is printed. The `.Renviron` file is in the app root directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `readRenviron()` with the path to .Renviron at the beginning of your script, and then calling `Sys.getenv()`.

Comment: You could export the variable in ~/.bash_profile is suppose.

Comment: From a security standpoint, is it safe to deploy `.Renviron` to shinyapps.io?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bill Ash suggests in the comments, using `readRenviron()` at the beginning of the script worked for me:

````
---
title: "Test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r}
readRenviron(".Renviron")
print(Sys.getenv("QUANDL_API_KEY"))
```
````